# Outlook: VSTO 4 + Linq Extensions?

Tags: .net, linq, outlook, vsto

I wrote an Outlook addon for 2007 using VSTO 3 and I had a hard time (not that hard) because Linq extensions for the outlook objects were not existent. Does VSTO 4 add support for Linq or is that a negative because it's still just wrapped COM?

My biggest concern is dealing with contacts. If no Linq, then what is an easy way to query against an outlook collection? I've seen how you can filter messages based on a query sytaxt (ex: "[Unread]=true"). Whatever the solution it has to be fast. One client has 33k contacts and another has over 72k. Yes, it's silly but that is how it is.

VSTO 3 doesnt offer GetEnumerator for can't even use a foreach statement

Edit: I'm using Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went ahead and solved my problem with the Linq extensions. http://programmersunlimited.wordpress.com/2011/01/08/linqqer-exposing-linq-extensions-on-non-ienumerableiqueriable-collections/

Answer (score 1):

I've never used LINQ, but you can basically use any API (.NET or otherwise) within a VSTO project like any other Visual Studio project (aside from Web components of course).

You can use the Table object for fast, SQL style queries:

Enumerating, Searching, and Filtering Items in a Folder: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869362.aspx

Comment: The link you gave was helpful overall, but I am looking for Linq specific answer. Suppose I should edit my question to include the fact that I'm using .NET and Visual Studio 2010.